# sql max(val1,val2)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

is there some way to determine the max value out of two values in SQL?

I use the mod function:

```
MOD(cnt, cnt/100)
```

This yields a division by 0 error when cnt is smaller than 100. I therefore would like something like this:

```
MOD(cnt, MAX(cnt/100, 1))
```

Comment: `greatest(a, b)`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use greatest

```
SELECT greatest(a, b, c) FROM your_table;
```